# convert multiple dataframe columns int64 dtype to equivalent of NUMBER(20,3) datatype of oracle

Tags: python, pandas, oracle, sqlalchemy, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am trying to insert dataframe in oracle DB table but some of columns in table has datatype as **NUMBER(20,3)**

I am assuming this is float .

How can  convert my column having datatype as **int64** to **NUMBER(20,3)** equivalent as it is giving **invalid identifier error** .

Comment: check out the `dtype=` argument to `.to_sql()`

Comment: One problem is that `int64` is up to 20 digits when written in base 10. On the other hand, `number(20,3)` reserves 3 digits for the decimal part (which you don't need!) which only leaves 17 digits for the integer part (which is the only thing you need). There is absolutely no way you can map very large `int64` values to `number(20,3)`. The correct data type is `number(20,0)`. But this has nothing to do with `invalid identifier` - that is a totally unrelated issue.

Answer (score 0):

`number(20, 3)` in Oracle means that column accepts numeric value which have 20 digits in total, and 3 out of those 20 are reserved for decimals. For example:

```
SQL> create table test (id number, value number(20, 3));

Table created.
```

Let's insert some values:

```
SQL> insert into test (id, value) values (1, 12.43);

1 row created.

SQL> insert into test (id, value) values (2, 12.4356);

1 row created.

SQL> insert into test (id, value) values (3, 12345678901234567.987);

1 row created.
```

Table contents: no surprises:

```
SQL> select * from test;

        ID      VALUE
---------- ----------
         1      12,43
         2     12,436
         3 1,2346E+16
```

What if you insert more than 3 decimal digits? Oracle will perform *round*:

```
SQL> insert into test (id, value) values (4, 12.4327);

1 row created.
```

---

But, you reported **invalid identifier** error. That has nothing to do with contents you're inserting, but invalid column name. Have a look: I "renamed" the `id` column to `idxyz` and Oracle raised error you mentioned:

```
SQL> insert into test (idxyz, value) values (5, 123);
insert into test (idxyz, value) values (5, 123)
                  *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00904: "IDXYZ": invalid identifier


SQL>
```

---

Therefore, check statement you use, looks like you misspelled one (or more) column names. Mind double quotes around column names (in Oracle, we usually don't use them) and - if you do have double quotes - mind letter case as well.

---

Oh, yes: how to convert `int64` to `number(20, 3)`? No idea, I don't use Python.